# How to config default gateway for Windows 10 OpenVPN client?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I set up my OpenVPN server and make client script like this:

```
client
proto udp
remote my.server.ip.addr port
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name servers name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns
verb 3
```

It almost works, except that Windows could not recognize the connection("no network access" on TAP adapter). So I had to manually set the TAP's default gateway to 10.8.0.1.

I wonder if there is a more "automatic" way to make sure the connection find its gateway rather than config TAP's default gateway for each machine.